# Protractor - How to locate element by custom (non HTML) attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am using Selenium WebDriver and Protractor to run e2e tests on my angular project.
Let's say I have an element like:

```
<div my-directive my-unique-id="abc123"></div>
```

How can locate the above element.
I tried with `element(by.css('div[my-unique-id="abc123"]'));`, but it gives a NoSuchElementError.

If I try with HTML attributes like, for example, I want to locate:

```
<a title="myTitle" href="">Click me</a>
```

I was able to locate the element correctly using `element(by.css('a[title="myTitle"]'))`

How do I locate the element with custom attributes, if it does not have any standard HTML attributes?

Comment: The syntax is correct. Does you directive render as a div with an attribute my-unique-id="abc123"? Check the element that is rendered in the browser using the developer tools and test it with $('your-css-selector'). It should work the same way in protractor.

Comment: Agree with @AndresD, the most likely cause for this is that your directive replaces the current element it's defined on with its own template. Check the element in devtools to make sure you have the right CSS selector.

Answer (score 18):

Try to use xpath:

```
element(by.xpath('//div[@my-unique-id="abc123"]'))
```

or only by attribute

```
element(by.xpath('//div[@my-unique-id]'))
```

Answer (score 4):

try using:

```
element(by.css('[my-unique-id="abc123"]'))
```

it's easier and more readable than xpath for simple cases.

more about xpath syntax and when it is usefull: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp