# Locate element by a presence of a custom attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

How do you locate all those elements that has particular custom attribute in Protractor? I found similar questions on Stackoverflow and on net, but they uses xpath which puts restriction on tag.

```
element(by.xpath('//div[@custom-attribute]'))
```

As oppose to above example, I don't want to put restriction on tag since we have different tags with the same custom attribute. I'd like locate all elements with the attribute regardless of tag. Is that possible?

Comment: Can't you use something like `document.querySelectorAll('div[attribute]')`?

Comment: Since this custom attribute is defined no just on div elements but others like buttons, hyperlinks and maybe other tags, I'm not sure that's possible. ..unless I have that statements for all other tags.

Comment: So? Just leave out the `div`.

Comment: First of all, don't edit comments into your question. I chose that dupe target as it also asks how to find elements _"by attribute"_.

Comment: @Cerbrus Correct me if I'm wrong, that question asks finding element by attribute value which is "hidden". Not by attribute name.

Comment: It's the same concept. Ignore the "hidden" filter.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not completely sure this is a direct duplicate..I'd reopen, what do you think?

Comment: Then I have [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059657/how-to-select-element-in-protractor-by-html-attribute-when-value-contains) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826579/protractor-find-element-by-attribute) [targets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629606/protractor-how-to-locate-element-by-custom-non-html-attributes) for you. This may not be the best target, but the question is a duplicate, for sure. You can re-close it with a better target if you wish, @alecxe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [*CSS selector locator*](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css):

```
element.all(by.css('[custom-attribute]'));
```

Or, via the `$$` shortcut:

```
$$('[custom-attribute]');
```

`[custom-attribute]` is an *[attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)* that would match any element having  `custom-attribute` attribute.

Comment: Couldn't the result of an ordinary `querySelectorAll` be passed to `element.all()`? Or am I mistaken in the assumption that native JS funcitonality is available there?

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah, there is no *"direct"* access to `querySelectorAll()`, but you can theoretically do that via [`executeScript()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript) or inside a custom locator - some of the bult-in protractor locators actually use `querySelectorAll` internally - for instance - the `by.repeater()` ([source](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/7da9c3a910bb000b30bf9ba82ef48c64bd751709/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L177)). Thanks, good question (have not downvoted your answer though).

Comment: I was kinda surprised at the -3. But since this is protractor's "native" query selector method, this is the better answer, any way.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah, -3 was definitely too much. On the bright side - you can get the "peer pressure" badge (if not had before).

Comment: I tried this approach but I'm not sure how to iterate the returned collection. I tried foreach and even tried calling click on the collection to see if it does anything. I get "Could not find testability for element."

Comment: @user30646 well, that might be a separate question, but see if [`each()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) works for you.

Comment: I also tried each and it doens't work. But with the help of my coworker, I found the culprit. It's because I didn't set useAllAngular2AppRoots to True in my config. Now works like a charm. Thanks for your help!