# Protractor - Giving "could not find testability for element" error when accessing element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

I'm running into issue with Protractor when accessing variable that stores return value of "elements.all". I'm fairly new to Protractor, so I wasn't sure how to select elements by custom attribute. Luckily, I received a suggestion, when I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467770/locate-element-by-a-presence-of-a-custom-attribute?noredirect=1#comment68180274_40467770) in another post. I was suggested to try out - "*element.all(by.css('[mycustom-id]'));*". But I'm not sure if that statement works or not since I'm getting "*Could not find testability for element*" error. It is also possible that I'm incorrectly iterating the object. I appreciate if anyone of you can point out my mistake. Thanks.

**Spec.JS**

```
var settings = require(__dirname + '/setting.json');
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() { 
    var target = element.all(by.css('[mycustom-id]')); 

    beforeEach(function() {
       browser.get(settings.url);
    });     

    it('Test mouseover', function() {       

       // This does not work
       target.each(function(item){
          //Do some stuff here
       });     

       // This does not work either
       target.count().then(function(x){
         console.log("Total--" + x);
       });
    });

});
```

**index.html**

```
<div>
    <a mycustom-id="123" href=''>HELLO1</a>
    <a mycustom-id="211" href=''>HELLO2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting this error because I need to set useAllAngular2AppRoots to true in config file. So if anyone having similar issue, make sure you have useAllAngular2AppRoots set to True.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to put things outside of Jasmine functions, i.e. outside of `it()`, `beforeAll()` etc.  Protractor uses those Jasmine functions to manage the control flow.

So I'm guessing that it is trying to create those webElements way before it should be.  Move your element locator inside the `it()` block.

```
it('Test mouseover', function() {       
   var target = element.all(by.css('[mycustom-id]')); 
   target.each(function(item){
      //Do some stuff here
   });
});
```

Comment: I tried that too, but still getting "Could not find testability for element" whenever I access "target". Thanks for reply.

Comment: Interesting.  Does the error give a failing line of code, is it the `it()` block?  I'm suspicious of the browser.get()

Comment: It's probably from "target.each" line. Because as soon as I comment out that line, the error is gone. It just does not let me access "target"

Comment: Huh, weird. Never seen that error before either.  `target.count()...` throws the same error?  Also what version of Protractor are you on?

Comment: Yes, this line throws the same error - "console.log(target.count());". I'm using Protractor 4.0.10.

Comment: Hmm I'm completely lost then, both the locator and webElement functions are perfectly valid code... sorry :(

Comment: Ok with the help from my cooworker, I figured out. I just need to set userAllAngular2AppRoots to true in config file. But thanks a lot for your help.